# mysql regular expression to get exact row sets

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID FROM REPORT where ID NOT LIKE '%-G'AND ID NOT LIKE '%-H';
```

The above query isnt returning what I expect. It is returning 5 row sets when it should 6. 6 ID matches the condition of query. Do I need to use a regular expression to get the right row sets? I have tried `'%\-G'` with single backslash and double backslash `'%\\-G'` both return the desired 6 row sets. Which should it be?

```
Sample data: 
87878
54545
21545-G
45487
45454
45458
78741
23232-H
```

Comment: Please let us know sample data in your database tables and the expected results of your query

Comment: Works for me, returning the expected six rows when I try it with your sample data in a table. Do you have some strange data types or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'%\-G'` this is the correct way of doing it and not `'%\\-G'`

For further reference follow : [MYSQL Escape Sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences)